# Is there a link where i can know how react native depends on android folder and Android depends on sdkmanager for an existing project?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-flatlist, react-native-firebase

So the problem is pretty general. I was trying to use and existing project which was created few months ago and was in working condition is somebody's laptop. So I cloned it into mine and its showing error like

Android environment ..
lot more error on XCode
But as I said it was totally working find in someone else laptop few months ago

I would like to study how the hell react-native is depending upon android and android depending on sdk manager